# do I understand the difference between instance attributes and class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

Let's say I have a method and a class:

```
def my_method(self):
    self.mark = 'Knopfler'

class MySubclass(object)
    my_method = my_method
```

I can think of 3 or 4 ways to use my_method within another class.

Case 1:
If I want to have access to my_method within yet another class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_subclass = MySubclass()
```

am I correct in thinking that this will allow me to use my_method on an instance like this:

```
my_inst = MyClass()
my_inst.my_subclass.my_method()
```

This seems to work like I expect, but if I do it like this:
Case 2:

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_subclass = MySubclass

my_inst = MyClass()
my_inst2 = MyClass()
my_inst.my_subclass.my_method()
```

as I understand it, the previous line will apply `my_method` to both `my_inst` and `my_inst2`.  Is that correct?

Case 3:
Another way to get my_method as an attribute of MyClass is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_method = my_method
```

and as I understand it, when I have multiple instances of MyClass, applying my_method will affect only the instance to which it is bound.  Is that correct?

Case 4 (last one):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_method = my_method
```

and the problem with this final method is that it seems to create my_method as an unbound method, which does not suit my needs.  Is there way to add an existing method as a bound instance method in a class definition?

Ok.  That is all.  Please let me know which of these four cases makes the most sense to use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your last case, you can bind a method to a class instance with `MethodType`:

```
import types

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_method = types.MethodType(my_method, self)
```